# Writting to cells that are out of data range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to write to some empty cells that are out of Google Sheet data range. I have the following code:

```
var ValueSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ValueSheet');
var myValueRange = ValueSheet.getDataRange();
var values = myValueRange.getValues();
var columnToCheck = ValueSheet.getRange("C:C").getValues();
var lastRow = getLastRow(columnToCheck);

values[lastRow + 1][3] = "-"; // TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined
```

The `lastRow` variable gets me the last row with data based on the `columnToCheck`. So if I have my last value on row 50, the `lastRow` value will be 50, but I need to write to the cell bellow it. Bellow is also the method I use to get the last row.

```
  function getLastRow(range){

  var rowNum = 0;
  var blank = false;
  for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++){

    if(range[row][0] === "" && !blank){
      rowNum = row;
      blank = true;

    }else if(range[row][0] !== ""){
      blank = false;
    }
  }
  return rowNum;
}
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: ValueSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,4).setValue("Hello World");

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `.getRange(row, column)` to access the desired cell. In this case you can use `.getRange(lastRow + 1, 4)` to access the row immediately below in the desired column (Keep in mind that the starting index is 1 in this case).

With the function `.setValue()` you will be able to write in the desired cell.

### References:

[Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)